# Would a metal detector on Mars be usable or would the "soil" return too many false positives?

Tags: mars

Also do we have any idea how deep some of the ore is?
Edit: 
I can't believe I left this that vague.  Iron.  I'm talking about iron.

Comment: Hmm... what ore? Has there been any detection of ore? Can you add some information about the ore of which you speak? The more you explain the context of your question, the easier it is to write an answer that you'll find helpful.

Comment: Sorry about that, updated.

Comment: Thanks for the update! I'm wondering if you can mention why you think there is iron ore on Mars. If it's been observed, can you mention how it's known to be there and add a link to where you've seen this observation described? If it's just been suggested, can you mention/add a link to where you've seen it suggested? I think it's very likely that it's there, but just for the purposes of writing a good stackexchange question, it's better to add links or citations to where factual information comes from. It's also just helpful to readers like me who are curious about what's known about Mars.

Comment: For example this suggests there is Iron, but there's no mention of an actual measurement *proving the existence* of iron ore below the surface of Mars; it just seems to suggest that Mars is a lot like Earth. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ore_resources_on_Mars#Direct_evidence_for_useful_materials

Comment: @uhoh Well, there is the common-sense-driven popular opinion that since Mars is rust-red in color, it must be rich in actual iron deposits. These points aren't really connected from a geology viewpoint, but kinda make sense from an everyman's viewpoint, I guess.

Comment: @theBigDream While martian dust does have a red color due to iron oxides, that does not point to the existence of iron deposits on Mars.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars_surface_color#Reason_for_red_and_its_extensiveness

Comment: @DanilaSmirnov I think there is definitely proof that there is iron on the surface of Mars and in surface rocks from alpha-particle induced X-ray spectra, for example as shown in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_particle_X-ray_spectrometer#Specific_instruments and possibly seen in X-ray spectra from orbit. Since it's a rocky planet with relatively high density, ancient volcanic activity, etc. it's hard to imagine no sources of enriched iron somewhere. Let's see if we can find evidence. Maybe Mars Global Surveyor magnetic field maps? https://photojournal.jpl.nasa.gov/jpeg/PIA02059.jpg

Comment: @theBigDream you might consider asking about the use of metal detector-type devices to look for metal ore deposits on Earth in (earthscience SE](https://photojournal.jpl.nasa.gov/jpeg/PIA02059.jpg). You can try to get a better understanding of the technical issues there, separately from the Mars-specific issues here. As long as the questions are not identical, there's nothing wrong with asking *related questions* in different SE sites.

Comment: A metal detector would detect metal but not necessarily also ore. Especially dectors for electrially conducting metals.

Comment: It may depend on how the metal detector has been "tuned" or calibrated. When looking for gold in a region with a lot red soil because of the iron in the soil, metal detectors work better if they are "tuned"/calibrated. If you want to look for iron deposits the metal detector may need to be calibrated for iron, but that would be difficult because there are many different types of iron deposits for bog iron ore,which contains about 30%

Answer (score 3):

It may depend on how the metal detector has been "tuned" or calibrated.

When looking for gold in a region with a lot red soil that contains iron, metal detectors work better if they are "tuned"/calibrated to find gold.

If you want to look for iron deposits the metal detector may need to be calibrated for iron, but that would be difficult because there are many different types of iron deposits for bog iron ore, which contains about 30% Fe to [Hematite](https://www.britannica.com/science/hematite), which is 70% Fe.

From what is currently in the public domain, calibrating for the [hematite "blueberries"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hematite) on Mars may be the best option. This could be done on Earth by creating spherules from local hematite, similar in size to those on Mars, and mixing it with various types of iron rich soil and test how various metal detectors respond.

Comment: Definite need for calibration of of the metal detector.  I built one and spent months wondering why it "wouldn't work" detecting objects on/in the ground. I knew the metal detector worked because it could pick out nails in the house walls.  Finally a "light bulb" went off in my head.  I lived in a city built on very large ironsand deposits, in the South Taranaki Bight of New Zealand.  Such rich ironsand that for 20 years the government made millions selling our worthless earth to Japan who made ships and cars, etc out of it. Duh! - to me.